# How to load content into lightbox-like overlay

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, css

I am making a gallery which loads in the images with php and mysql.
Now I'm trying to incorporate a lightbox-like overlay, but with specific, editable, html.
So, that I can add the elements which I want displayed (image, title, description, extended description) which are loaded in via php and mysql.

I've googled a bunch of lightboxes but they weren't really what I was looking for, and in addition to that it has to be licensed so that I can use it commercially. (So I'd like to do it myself, if possible)

My current html code, loaded by php and mysql:

```
<div class='view view-tenth'>
<img src='".$images['orig']."' alt='".$images['name']."' />
<div class='mask'>
<h2>".$images['model']."</h2>
<p>A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart.</p>
<a href='#' class='info'>Read More</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Basically, I want the overlay to load when clicked on 'read more', but with the specific title, description etc of that certain image.

But the thing is, I'm not really sure how to code this.
Does anyone have suggestions on how to handle this?

**-edit-**
So basically what I'm looking for is a way to transfer the php data which is retrieved from my database, via -for example- the HREF link, to the overlay, so that when clicked on an image, the right information (title, description etc) is displayed.

I'm struggling with transferring the data, not with making the actual HTML overlay. Hope that clears everything up.

**-edit 2-**
Got the colorbox jquery working... http://imandragrafie.nl/demo/ontwerp_test.php But now I need the info loaded into the box :)

**No fancybox** please, I can't use fancy box for commercial websites.

Comment: Ok.. Let me know if i understood... You want to click in a link that have to go to the back-end and get others images that in database and show then in a lightbox.. right?

Comment: Well, kind of. When you click the link (which is a php-element that has been echoed) you have to see an overlay with the specific information that belongs to that link (such as name and description of an image). If you click another link, you'll get the overlay with the info that belongs to that image, and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save your respective data in json and can show up it while clicking on `read more` as below:

Below is small sample code in which I have data in `jsonObj` var and store respective data in `var html` element and then I have `console.log(html)` to show that data. you can modify the code with your requirement to get the data from database.

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class='view view-tenth'>
    <img src='' alt='' width="25" height="25" />
    <div class='mask'>
        <h2>".$images['model']."</h2>
        <p>A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart.</p>
        <a href='#' class='info' data-value="img1">Read More</a>
    </div>
    <img src='' alt='' width="25" height="25" />
    <div class='mask'>
        <h2>".$images['model']."</h2>
        <p>A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart.</p>
        <a href='#' class='info' data-value="img2">Read More</a>
    </div>
    <img src='' alt='' width="25" height="25" />
    <div class='mask'>
        <h2>".$images['model']."</h2>
        <p>A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart.</p>
        <a href='#' class='info' data-value="img3">Read More</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery Code:**

```
var jsonObj = {
    "img1":{
        "id": "img1",
        "image": "path/to/image1.jpg",
        "title": "This is title 1",
        "desc": "A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart."
    },
    "img2":{
        "id": "img2",
        "image": "path/to/image2.jpg",
        "title": "This is title 2",
        "desc": "A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart."
    },
    "img3":{
        "id": "img3",
        "image": "path/to/image3.jpg",
        "title": "This is title 3",
        "desc": "A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart."
    }
}
$(function(){
    $(".info").on("click", function(){
        var val = $(this).data("value"),
            html = "";

        for(var i in jsonObj){
            if(jsonObj[i].id == val){
                html += "jsonObj.img1.id = " + jsonObj[i].id + "\n";
                html += "jsonObj.img1.image = " + jsonObj[i].image + "\n";
                html += "jsonObj.img1.title = " + jsonObj[i].title + "\n";
                html += "jsonObj.img1.desc = " + jsonObj[i].desc + "\n";
            }
        }
        console.log(html);
    });
});
```

You can pass this `html` variable as data in lightbox window.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok, have your jquery in my code (I'm echoing the lines with php within the script tag, so I get the whole array, hope that doesn't cause problems?), but how can I get the html in the lightbox?

Comment: Just installed colorbox by the way: Just need to know how to get the information into the box. (And side-question: If the description is longer, for example a paragraph of 10 lines, is it possible to display next to or below the image instead of above? Used the design of example 3)

Comment: There are two ways:
1 - You can append the content in `html` in a div in page and use below method of colorbox
$(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%"});

OR

2 - You can directly call the `html` variable with below code:
// Called directly with HTML
$.colorbox({html:"<h1>Welcome</h1>"});

Comment: Not sure I follow (not very familiar with jQuery). Can you give a fiddle? Right now I've got this: http://imandragrafie.nl/demo/ontwerp_test.php You can't see the php code but I don't thing that's needed, right? Since everything is loaded into jquery?

Comment: OK it's getting there, but the colorbox overlay is very, very small and when closed it's just redirecting to the #cboxOverlay div.. The image isn't disappearing. Also, I'm missing the colorbox controls (previous, next, the x in the corner instead of the 'close' at the bottom). I had to disable the colorbox css because otherwise it was a complete mess.. (just a [vertical scrollable] image bar, but no close button or anything) Please help. Link stays the same: imandragrafie.nl/demo/ontwerp_test.php

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with pure css, if you like. Below is a sample.

## http://codepen.io/fauverism/pen/pvvKKL

### CSS

```
/* Container */
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.modal {

    /* Overlay page content */
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    z-index: 10000;

    /* Transition opacity on open */
    -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 500ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 500ms ease-in;

    /* Hide for now */
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}

/* Show modal */
.modal:target {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
    /* at time of writing (Feb 2012), pointer-events not supported by Opera or IE */
}

/* Content */
.modal > div {
    width: 500px;
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10% auto;

    /* Default minimise animation */
    -webkit-animation: minimise 500ms linear;
    -moz-animation: minimise 500ms linear;
    animation: minimise 500ms linear;

    /* Prettify */
    padding: 30px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    background: #fff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #ccc);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #ccc);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #ccc);
    background: linear-gradient(#fff, #ccc);
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
}

/* Override animation on modal open */
.modal:target > div {
    -webkit-animation-name: bounce;
    -moz-animation-name: bounce;
    animation-name: bounce;
}

.modal h2 {
    font-size: 36px;
    padding: 0 0 20px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.1,0.1,1);
    box-shadow: 0 3px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
  }
  55% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.08,1.08,1);
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.95,0.95,1);
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
    box-shadow: 0 3px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes minimise {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.1,0.1,1);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes bounce {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scale3d(0.1,0.1,1);
    box-shadow: 0 3px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
  }
  55% {
    -moz-transform: scale3d(1.08,1.08,1);
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0);
  }
  75% {
    -moz-transform: scale3d(0.95,0.95,1);
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
    box-shadow: 0 3px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes minimise {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scale3d(0.1,0.1,1);
  }
}

@keyframes bounce {
  0% {
    transform: scale3d(0.1,0.1,1);
    box-shadow: 0 3px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
  }
  55% {
    transform: scale3d(1.08,1.08,1);
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0);
  }
  75% {
    transform: scale3d(0.95,0.95,1);
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
    box-shadow: 0 3px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
  }
}

@keyframes minimise {
  0% {
    transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale3d(0.1,0.1,1);
  }
}

/* Modal close link */
.modal a[href="#close"] {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    color: transparent;
}

/* Reset native styles */
.modal a[href="#close"]:focus {
    outline: none;
}

/* Create close button */
.modal a[href="#close"]:after {
    content: 'X';
    display: block;

    /* Position */
    position: absolute;
    right: -10px;
    top: -10px;
    width: 1.5em;
    padding: 1px 1px 1px 2px;

    /* Style */
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    }

    .modal a[href="#close"]:focus:after,
    .modal a[href="#close"]:hover:after {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
}

.modal a[href="#close"]:focus:after {
    outline: 1px solid #000;
}

/* Open modal */
a.openModal {
    margin: 1em auto;
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    background: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    background: #fff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #ddd);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #ddd);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #ddd);
    background: linear-gradient(#fff, #ddd);
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

a.openModal:hover,
a.openModal:focus {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #ccc);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #ccc);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #ccc);
    background: linear-gradient(#fff, #ccc);
}
```

### HTML

```
<aside id="example" class="modal">
    <div>
        <h2>Modal box</h2>
        <a href="#close" title="Close">Close</a>
    </div>
</aside>

<a href="#example" class="openModal">Open</a>
```

Comment: Could you make a fiddle? Because when I test out yours it doesn't do anything except show a blank page :)

Comment: Besides, I've looked at colorbox, but how to get the image info in there without making (unnecessary) extra 'overlay' divs?

Comment: Ok, so then I'd have the overlay.. But how to get the content in the overlay?

Comment: Are you interested in not doing this in php? Angular would be an option that has fairly easy data binding

Comment: Well, I don't know anything about angular, but if that's the only option that works.. I'd rather have jquery / php / css/ html solutions though

Comment: You can use onclick event with jquery on read more button that send request to php file that pulls content from database and then return result and put it on the overlay.

Answer (score 1):

After your edit I think you need some kind of ajax to fetch your data and put it into the overlay.

You can simply do that with ajax in jquery. Something like this should work:

```
$( "#doit" ).click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/get/data.php",
    context: document.body
  }).done(function() {
  $( this ).addClass( "done" );
  });
});
```

Read more about ajax in jquery [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

**Update** after comments.

Your

```
/get/data.php
```

can either return a json object or (ready to display) html.

In the first case you have to convert your data structure with javascript into html.

In the second case you can do that on the php (server) side.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with ajax, can you use it to fetch multiple 'arrays' (lack of a better term) of data? And if you have that, you just load it into the overlay how?

Comment: Your /get/data.php can either return a json object or the ready to display html. In the first case you have to convert your data structure with javascript into html. In the Second Case you can so that on the php side.

Comment: Could you create a fiddle or something? Because I'm not familiar with ajax and I don't know how to place the info in there..

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion.

to summarize ... you have a gallery page with pictures on it. They are linked to an overlay with more information on the pictures.

I used for something similar: http://fancybox.net/
Try the google maps link on the page .. which looks like this:

```
<a class="various iframe" href="http://maps.google.com/?output=embed&amp;f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=London+Eye,+County+Hall,+Westminster+Bridge+Road,+London,+United+Kingdom&amp;hl=lv&amp;ll=51.504155,-0.117749&amp;spn=0.00571,0.016512&amp;sll=56.879635,24.603189&amp;sspn=10.280244,33.815918&amp;vpsrc=6&amp;hq=London+Eye&amp;radius=15000&amp;t=h&amp;z=17">Google maps (iframe)</a>
```

But your Overlay Link goes to another Page which only Shows the Information for the picure like this:

```
<a class="various iframe" href="/mygallerie/picturedetails.php?id=124"><img ... ></a>
```

So in my solution you have one PHP Page which list the pictures and Links them to the overlay with an id.

The second PHP Page is then shown in the Overlay.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle? That way I'll understand better.

Answer (score 0):

I would first load everything that you want separated in the lightbox into different divs using php. I would then default all the html css for the lightbox part to "display: none;". Then you can use jquery to make it so whatever you currently hover over (or click on ..etc) is switched from "display:none" to "display: block".

So to summarize. I would code all the content/html first, with all the possible views using php. Then I would use jQuery to control the views, so you only see the ones you want depending on what you click/hover. I have used this method a lot and it performs great for small projects.

Comment: But that would mean that I'd have as many 'overlay' divs as I have photo's. Seems that there could be a easier, -less code- solution, maybe with GET or something? Or do I see it wrong?

Comment: If you are using the same html that is simple. Just throw the image src's, names, and descriptions in an array and create a for loop that iterates through it. That way the loop does the work and you write the html once.

Comment: Could you give me an example? Because I don't exactly get how that works haha. Sounds to me that it will just loop through the info and images, which I don't want :P

Comment: Yes, this would absolutely loop through the info and images. So if you're not wanting to pursue that idea then this definitely isn't the way to go.

Comment: No, not the way to go then. I'd like to have a solution where the content is retrieved on the basis of -for example- the href link (that is 'made' with php variables that are retrieved from the database, so that every 'image' has a different content within the overlay, so that the right information is displayed for the right image. Hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is:
- Add a backdrop (A greyish transparent background)
- Add a box in the middle of the screen
- Place an image, a title and a description inside the box

Here is an example on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4tu9Lotg/

```
<body>

<div class="backdrop"></div>
<div class="box">
<center><h1>Title</h1></center>
<img class="boximg" src="http://free-hq-wallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/New-York-Sunset-1920x1080.jpg"/>
</div>
    </body>
```

and

```
.backdrop{
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
background-color: #000;
opacity: .5;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

.box{
position: absolute;
background-color: white;
top: 10%;
left: 10%;
width: 80%;
height: 80%;
border-radius: 13px;
}

.boximg {
position: absolute;
top: 16%;
left: 2%;
width: 96%;
height: 80%;
   }
```

Comment: Well, then I'd have the overlay, but how get the specific content in there? Because that depends on which image-link is clicked.